# Xamarin Android WCF para após entrar mais de 10 vezes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Tenho um app em xamarin android que consome um serviço wcf, quando eu instancio o serviço mais de 10 vezes o serviço cai e é preciso reiniciar-lo e quando ele vai reiniciar a barra precisa ir até o meio para parar o serviço e depois começa a carregar mais um pouco para iniciar.
Eu não sei o que posso estar fazendo errado pois sempre dou dispose() nos metodos então acredito que não seja isso, alguém pode me ajudar por favor??

```
public void Conectar(int chaveAdministrador, string cnpjEstabelecimento, string IP, string NomeBanco)
{
    sPropriedades ws = new sPropriedades();
    ws.Url = "http//"+IP+":2704/Fontes/"
    ws.CarregarBase(chaveAdministrador, cnpjEstabelecimento, IP, NomeBanco);
}
```

Quando eu executo essa função mais de 10 vezes na proxima ele não reponde mais, ai tenho que reiniciar
o serviço no PC

Essa é classe sPropriedade no serviço

```
ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
    public interface IsPropriedades
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void CarregarBase(int chaveAdministrador, string cnpjEstabelecimento, string IP, string NomeBanco);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class sPropriedades : IsPropriedades
    {
        public void CarregarBase(int chaveAdministrador, string cnpjEstabelecimento, string IP, string NomeBanco)
        {
            c_Propriedades.IP = IP;
            c_Propriedades.NomeBanco = NomeBanco;
            c_Propriedades.ChaveAdmin = chaveAdministrador;
            c_Propriedades.ChaveEmpresa = chaveAdministrador + "|1|" + cnpjEstabelecimento;
            c_Propriedades.ChaveCaixaDoTurno = c_Caixa_DB.BuscarChaveCaixaTurno();
            c_Propriedades.TurnoAberto = c_Caixa_DB.BuscarSituacaoTurno();
            c_Propriedades.Parametros = c_Parametros_DB.BuscarParametroFood();
        }
}
```

Comment: é difícil ter uma ideia sem ver o código do seu app e do serviço, poste seu código na pergunta

Comment: Primeiro eu referenciei o serviço na referencia do projeto .droid. Exemplo do código...

Comment: precisamos ver o código do serviço para entender a implementação... serviços não "caem" assim, deve ter algum erro de recurso preso, objetos não liberados, algo assim no seu código

Comment: por favor, edite sua pergunta e coloque esse comentário na pergunta, como código client, e também mostre o código do serviço

Comment: Coloque o código da classe sPropriedades, por favor.

Comment: Precisam de mais alguma informação? Eu achava que era problema de sessão mas eu aumentei a quantidade no App.config e mesmo assim não responde depois de 10 vezes parece que o servico fica carregado

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido! na verdade o problema era do lado do serviço que estva acumulando bastante conexões de banco de dados e não estavam fechando corretamente. Arrumei isso e funcionou !